# Joining two lists from each statement

Tags: c#

[image]

```
if (Settings.Default.All)
{
      List = new ObservableCollection<LexisNexis>(UnitOfWork.Query.Lexis.LexisForApprove2().OrderBy(x => x.TxnID).Reverse());             
}
if (Settings.Default.MLhuillier)
{
     List = new ObservableCollection<LexisNexis>(UnitOfWork.Query.Lexis.LexisForApprove2().Where(x => x.ServiceMode == "MLhuillier").OrderBy(x => x.TxnID).Reverse());
}
if (Settings.Default.BPI)
{
    List = new ObservableCollection<LexisNexis>(UnitOfWork.Query.Lexis.LexisForApprove2().Where(x => x.ServiceMode == "BPI").OrderBy(x => x.TxnID).Reverse());
}
```

I want to combine each list from each if statement that returns true. my program just return the last list. TYIA

Comment: Please don’t post code as images. They are text so include them as such, properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simplifying the code

The following should do what you want with little duplication and with at most one traversal through `LexisForApprove2`.

```
var orFilters = Settings.Default.All ? null : new List<string>();

if (!Settings.Default.All)
{
    if (Settings.Default.MLhuillier) orFilters.Add("MLhuillier");
    if (Settings.Default.BPI) orFilters.Add("BPI");
}

var l = orFilters == null
    ? UnitOfWork.Query.Lexis.LexisForApprove2() // Everything
    : orFilters.Any() 
        ? UnitOfWork.Query.Lexis.LexisForApprove2().Where(x => orFilters.Contains(x.ServiceMode))
        : new List<LexisNexis>(); // Not 'All' but no others allowed

List = new ObservableCollection<LexisNexis>(l.OrderByDescending(y => y.TxnID));
```

---

## `Distinct`

Just for the record, and not recommened for this case, you could use List's `AddRange` or Linq's `Union` followed by `Distinct`, which would work if the `LexisNexis` objects are good at comparing themselves with others :)

Comment: but what if the last 2 if statements are true.

Comment: Thank you so much Bro. It now works. thank you thank you.